# WebRTC native java/ android

Tags: java, webrtc

I am able to build the libjingle library and also build the AppRTCDemo App on Android. I am able to connect to peers and share audio and video successfully. Now I want to extend it to send data (say Text "HelloWorld"). I want to integrate DataChannel into it so that I can also send data through it.

I have few questions:

1. Is it possible to use DataChannel with native webrtc? I mean what I am trying to do is it supported ?
2. Is there any sample application or example that could solve this problem for me ?

Looking forwards for you support!

Comment: I find people say "native WebRTC" but to me the meaning is not clear. DO you mean you want to use DataChannel from java code on Android - or are you talking pure C++ - which is what is native for libjingle.

There are very few examples for Android Java

Comment: @ user1170897 can you please how did you achieve this can you please give me steps and AppRTCDemo source if possible?

Comment: did your AppRTCDemo worked out of the box after compiling or you had to do some setup, please explain more?

Comment: Step by step process to make APPRTC [link]http://andrii.sergiienko.me/?go=all/building-webrtc-demo-for-android/

Comment: @user1170897- Can you please explain how did you build libjingle? I have been struggling.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes it is supported. For more info about the exact interfaces take a look at

   `<libjingle-src>/talk/app/webrtc/java/src/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java`
   `<libjingle-src>/talk/app/webrtc/java/src/org/webrtc/DataChannel.java`
2. As far as I know there isn't any examples